# Need help logging user's IP's upon creating an account

Tags: php

I'm very new to coding PHP (VERY NEW)
and I've created a login/register system for my website I currently have a working system that inputs their "id  int(11)" Username, Email, and password. I would now like to add an ip column that will log their IP's upon creating an account.
(Just a site for me to test things and learn things)

***MY QUESTION OBVIOUSLY IS HOW CAN I ADD TO MY CODE A WAY TO INPUT USER'S IP ADDRESSES ONCE THEY CREATE AN ACCOUNT ON MY SITE....***

***My current code for server.php is***

```
<?php 
session_start();

// variable declaration
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array(); 
$_SESSION['success'] = "";

// connect to database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','password','db')
 or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    // receive all input values from the form
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
    $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

    // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled
    if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
    if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
    if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }

    if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
        array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
    }

    // register user if there are no errors in the form
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password)
                  VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
        mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
        header('location: index.php');

        mysql_error();
    }

}

// ... 

// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: index.php');
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question

Comment: Learn how to use prepared statements. You're open to SQL injection here. `mysqli_escape_string()` is not enough to protect you from all attacks.

Comment: @symcbean You can clearly see i said 
"I would now like to add an ip column that will log their IP's upon creating an account." 
I didn't come here to tell you about what I want to do...read the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to get the visitor’s/client’s [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) is using the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` or `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` variables.

However, sometimes this does not return the correct IP address of the visitor, so we can use some other server variables to get the IP address.

The below both functions are equivalent with the difference only in how and from where the values are retrieved.

getenv() is used to get the value of an environment variable in PHP.

```
// Function to get the client IP address
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

$_SERVER is an array that contains server variables created by the web server.

```
// Function to get the client IP address
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

Comment: Now how exactly would I implement this code into my server.php so that it'll log each time someone creates an account? Thank you for the info!

Comment: Keep in mind that anything except `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` can easily be tampered with if someone with malicious intent wants to pose as someone else and crafts an HTTP request with an `X-Forwarded-For` header in which they can put anything they want. Check the remote address against known trusted proxy IPs before trusting whatever the other headers say.

Comment: @WollyLinka You can simply use `$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` and then save the value of $ipaddress in your MySQL table.

Comment: @Ank I am having some issues with where to put the code. as I said I'm very new to this so it's pretty confusing.